How to customize List of Figures and List of Tables entries in the Table of Contents?
Greetings!
In my simple LaTeX document (intended as an example), I want to make specific modifications to the Table of Contents (ToC). My goal is to change the appearance of the "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" titles in the ToC. I would like these entries to be italicized, non-bold, and to have a small margin between them.
I'm aiming for something similar to this:

The example above is provided by John Lienhard in the MIT Thesis Template, available here: MIT Thesis Template on Overleaf.
I've tried using packages like tocbibind, tocloft, and tocbasic, but none have given the result I'm looking for. Specifically, tocloft affected the main titles (which I could later modify) but didn’t modify the ToC entries as intended.
Here’s my current code:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\title{ToC - A Test}
\author{José Areia}
\date{November 2024}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\normalsize\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\normalsize\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\normalsize\huge\scshape}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents\clearpage
\listoffigures\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\section{Paper Organisation}
Paper organisation

\chapter{Related Work}
Related Work

\chapter{Conclusion}
Conclusion

\end{document}

This produces the following output:

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this formatting?

The mitthesis.cls documentclass file contains the modification of the font from bold to italics. You can copy it from there in your own document. Because the commands used there contains an @ symbol you need to put \makeatletter and \makeatother around the copied code.
% modification code copied from mitthesis.cls v1.17 2024/11/02 line 155 and further
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{toc}\contentsname}{}{} % placement matters.

%% Code to accommodate latex tagging. Rework once LaTeX3 team have finalized tagging structures.
%% No guarantee that this hack is hierarchically correct.
%% Current latex-lab places tags around \@schapter, which is harder to deal with here.

\ProvideDocumentCommand\MakeLinkTarget{sO{}m}{}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter*{\listfigurename}}{\chapter*{\phantomsection\listfigurename}\MakeLinkTarget*{listoffigures}\addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\listfigurename}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter*{\listtablename}}{\chapter*{\phantomsection\listtablename}\MakeLinkTarget*{listoftables}\addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\listtablename}}{}{}

\NewCommandCopy\l@frontmatter\l@chapter
\NewCommandCopy\l@backmatter\l@chapter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@frontmatter}{0}% prevent warning, see hyperref manual Sec. 13.3
\providecommand*{\toclevel@backmatter}{0}

%% if you want different formatting for front/back matter, change here (cf. report.cls). 
\patchcmd{\l@frontmatter}{\bfseries}{\itshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@frontmatter}{\nobreak\hfil}{\upshape\nobreak\hfil}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@frontmatter}{1.0em}{3pt}{}{} 
\patchcmd{\l@backmatter}{\bfseries}{\itshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@backmatter}{\nobreak\hfil}{\upshape\nobreak\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{ToC - A Test}
\author{José Areia}
\date{November 2024}


\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\maketitle
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\section{Paper Organisation}
Paper organisation

\chapter{Related Work}
Related Work

\chapter{Conclusion}
Conclusion

\end{document}


The \hypersetup{pageanchor=false} setting for the \maketitle command is to suppress a hyperref warning, see pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (nam e{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored.

It works as intended. Thank you very much for your kind and prompt response.

Out of curiosity, do you know how can change the appearance of both "Glossary" and "Acronyms" in ToC too? Thank you in advance.

Nevermind, I was able to do it by creating the following the command \newcommand{\glossarytoc}{\MakeLinkTarget*{glossary}\addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\glossaryname}} and place it right behind \printglossary.
Thank you.
